# Transport/Access local variables within async Task - API Controller

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I'm using a controller to do some actions using an external library. Now I want to change the controller to be async. How I can manage it to get access to the local variables. What is best practise?

Thanks!

This works, but not async!

```
        [HttpGet("save")]
        public IActionResult Save(string sessionID, string fileName, string format, string pageRange)
        {
            DocuViewareControllerActionsHandler.save(sessionID, ref fileName, format, pageRange, out HttpStatusCode statusCode, out string reasonPhrase, out byte[] content, out string contentType);

            if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return File(content, contentType, fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode((int)statusCode, reasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

Does not work! I have not idea to access the variables, defined with OUT. Is there a better way?

```
        [HttpGet("save")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Save(string sessionID, string fileName, string format, string pageRange)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DocuViewareControllerActionsHandler.save(sessionID, ref fileName, format, pageRange, out HttpStatusCode statusCode, out string reasonPhrase, out byte[] content, out string contentType);
            });

            if (statusCodeTask == HttpStatusCode.OK) // statusCode does not exists in the current context ???
            {
                return File(content, contentType, fileName); // content, contentType does not exists in the current context ???
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode((int)statusCode, reasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define those variables outside of `Task` like this:

```
[HttpGet("save")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(string sessionID, string fileName, string format, string pageRange)
{
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    byte[] content = null;
    string contentType = null;
    string reasonPhrase = null;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DocuViewareControllerActionsHandler.save(sessionID, ref fileName, format, pageRange, out statusCode, out reasonPhrase, out content, out contentType);
    });

    if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return File(content, contentType, fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return StatusCode((int)statusCode, reasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

But note, that's usually a bad practice to use `out` parameters. Better way is to wrap them in some class and return instance of this class from the method.

Note 2. What are you trying to achieve here? From what I can tell creating new Task here and awiting it does nothing. It executes `DocuViewareControllerActionsHandler.save` in different thread, yes, but rest of the code (`if (statusCodeTask...`) will still be executed only after `save` is done.

Comment: Hi,  
thanks for your answer.  
If I define the variables outside like you described I got an error `Use of unassigned local variable 'content'`. Therefore I have no glue how to do.  

You are right, for that case there is no further code to be executed. So I can spare to execute the call async. But there are other cases.  

I can not change the methods behavior "out" parameters, because that is a third party library.  

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Yes, my mistake. It doesn't know that those variables are assigned inside the task. Updated the answer, it should be valid now. But again, your initial version (without Task) is just fine, Task and await will not do anything for you here

Answer (score 0):

Local variables aren't initialized. You have to manually initialize them. Try like below:

```
public class TestClass
{

    public HttpStatusCode statusCode;
    public string reasonPhrase;
    public byte[] content;
    public string contentType;

    [HttpGet("save")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save(string sessionID, string fileName, string format, string pageRange)
    {

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DocuViewareControllerActionsHandler.save(sessionID, ref fileName, format, pageRange, out statusCode, out reasonPhrase, out content, out contentType);
        });

        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
        {
            return File(content, contentType, fileName); 
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode((int)statusCode, reasonPhrase);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure about making them global? (and public) This will just pollute the namespace since they are not intended to be used outside of Save method

Comment: Is there another way? DocuViewareControllerActionsHandler.save is a method from third party library!